# Java Enumeration vs Iteration vs ForLoop

Tags: java, loops, iterator, enumeration

What is the  difference between (Enumeration, Iterator, Loop) ??

In the following code each example (Enumeration, Iterator, Loop) gets the same output ]
but I need to know what is the real difference between them? Is there specific case where i should use one of them and cant use the others? any advantages in one of them over the others?

Comment: To begin with, you won't use `Vector` in a Java SE 5 or more application.

Comment: Iterators and Enumerators are better at obfuscation.

Comment: Read this tutorial if you want to appreciate the power of higher levels of abstraction:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Enumeration VS Iterator**

Iterator is mainly used with **non Thread safe Collection**. Iterator is designed in such a way that **it fails whenever concurrent modification are made to the Collections** i.e if a collection which is made for single Threaded environment is used in multithreaded environment and changes are made to it by Thread while it is being traversed then the traversing fails.

Enumeration is used only with **Thread safe Collection**. When such a collection is used in multithreaded environment consistency of the data is guarantee hence Enumeration never fails

For better understanding you should their Internal Working........

A Collection and its Iterator and Enumeration has a stronger HAS-A relation between them i.e Existence of both parties depends upon each other.

Comment: In real time which one should be used in which condition?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Enumation vs Iteration, from the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html):

> Iterator
>   takes the place of Enumeration in the Java Collections Framework.
>   Iterators differ from enumerations in two ways: **Iterators allow the
>   caller to remove elements from the underlying collection during the
>   iteration with well-defined semantics. Method names have been
>   improved.**

Answer (score 0):

If readability is important.

Prefer this

```
for (String s : listofStrings) 
    {
     ... 
    }
```

over

```
for (Iterator<String> iter = listofStrings.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); )
{
 String s = iter.next();
 ...
}
```

Note that if you need to delete elements as you iterate, you need to use Iterator.

For example,

```
List<String> list = getMyListofStrings(); 

    for (Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) 
    {
        String s = iter.next();
        if (someCondition) {
            iter.remove(); 
        }
    }
```

You can't use `for(String s : myList)` to delete an element in the list.
Also note that when iterating through an array, foreach (or enhanced for) can be used only to obtain the elements, you can't modify the elements in the array.

Comment: If you iterate backwards through the array, using plain old `for(int i=...)`, you can delete elements just fine.